# php json output trouble

Tags: php, json

I have `php` code that output `json` like this :

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var stateObj = { nilailumen: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
require 'koneksi.php';
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * from nilai_lumen WHERE id =(SELECT MAX(id) from nilai_lumen)");
try{
        $STH->execute();
        $result = array();

        while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                array_push($result, array(
        "lumensatu"=>$row['lumen_satu'],
        "lumendua"=>$row['lumen_dua'],
        "lumentiga"=>$row['lumen_tiga'],
        "lumenempat"=>$row['lumen_empat'],
        "celcius"=>$row['suhu_c'],
        "fahrenhait"=>$row['suhu_f'],
        ));
        }
        echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
        $DBH = null;
} catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some script in `javascript` above like this :

```
<script>
    var stateObj = { nilailumen: "bar" };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
</script>
```

When I run this page I get json like this

```
// {"result":[{"lumensatu":"11","lumendua":"10","lumentiga":"8","lumenempat":"10","celcius":"28","fahrenhait":"82"}]}
```

and my url change to bar.html

**Why I have some double slash from my json and how to fix it?**

Comment: Why are you preparing a query that has no parameters?

Comment: _and my url change to bar.html_ Isn't that what `history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");` is supposed to do

Comment: i just select my database and get some value .. i want to hide my url and it is work but i dont know why i get json like that (have double slash)

Comment: This is ignoring the base issue, but you could always use 

`echo substr(json_encode(array('result'=>$result)),2);`

Comment: thanks you @HowardP i change it like you suggest me and i get result like this ..

result":[{"lumensatu":"11","lumendua":"10","lumentiga":"8","lumenempat":"10","celcius":"28","fahrenhait":"82"}]}

why the bracket is gone ( {" )

Comment: Because the number parameter for substring is too high. Set it to `1`. If you come across an issue like this again, check the documentation for the function you're using. Here's a link to the documentation for substring: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php. This is a pretty basic issue you should be able to figure out yourself.